# Trying to Bind data from realtime database for a list view

Tags: c#, listview, xamarin, firebase-realtime-database, data-binding

I have a database like this up on firebase realtime db:

->petProfiles

```
->Node
     ->UserEmail
     ->PetName
     ->Breed
->Node
     ->UserEmail
     ->PetName
     ->Breed
 ->Node
     ->UserEmail
     ->PetName
     ->Breed
```

I would like to bind this data to make a list view however I just want to use the branches which have the same UserEmail (just show the loggedin users pets to them in a list view). However no data appears on screen. I think i'm populating my ObservableCollection wrong. Could you please give me some pointers.

viewmodel:

```
class MyIDPageViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    FirebaseHelper firebaseHelper = new FirebaseHelper();

    readonly IList<PetProfile> source;

    public ObservableCollection<PetProfile> PetInfo { get; private set; }
    public IList<PetProfile> EmptyPetInfo { get; private set; }

    public MyIDPageViewModel()
    {
        source = new List<PetProfile>();
        CreatePetProfileCollection();
        OnPropertyChanged();
    }


    private async void CreatePetProfileCollection()
    {
        var petProfiles = await firebaseHelper.GetAllUserPetInfos();
        if(petProfiles != null)
        {
            foreach (var groupitems in petProfiles)
            {
                source.Add(new PetProfile() { PetName = groupitems.PetName });
            }

        }
        
        PetInfo = new ObservableCollection<PetProfile>(source);
    }

    #region INotifyPropertyChanged
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
    #endregion
}
```

}

'''
Firebasehelper:

```
public async Task<List<PetProfile>> GetAllUserPetInfos()
    {
        var useremail = Preferences.Get("UserSignInEmail", "");

        var PetProfiles = await GetAllPetInfos();
        await firebase
          .Child("PetProfiles")
          .OnceAsync<PetProfile>();
        return PetProfiles.Where(a => a.UserEmail == useremail).ToList();
       
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways to go about this and there is one way why it isnt working ;)
So why does it not work?
Eventhought you're implementing the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface, you are never actually invoking the event. PropertyChangedEventHandler delegates added to the `PropertyChanged` event have to be invoked manually.
When doing
`PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));`
You're doing that, however you're not calling `OnPropertyChanged` anywhere in your code.

So how can you solve that issue.
1.

```
    public IList<PetProfile> EmptyPetInfo { 
        get => source;
        private set {
            if (value != source) {
                source = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(EmptyPetInfo));
            }
        }
    }
```

Call `OnPropertyChanged` in the setter of your ObservableCollection.

2.

```
    private async void CreatePetProfileCollection()
    {
        var petProfiles = await firebaseHelper.GetAllUserPetInfos();
        if(petProfiles != null)
        {
            PetInfo = new ObservableCollection<PetProfile>();
            foreach (var groupitems in petProfiles)
            {
                PetInfo.Add(new PetProfile() { PetName = groupitems.PetName });
            }
        }
    }
```

Add the objects to the ObservableCollection instead.

Edit: Missed to see that you are calling `OnPropertyChanged` without an argument from from your constructor. You have to provide the name of the property that you wish to have its value updated in the view.
Before calling `OnPropertyChanged` thought u are also executing an asynchronous method. The moment you are calling an asynchronous method, it is started on a new thread and the execution inside your constructor continues. Therefore `OnPropertyChanged` will be called, before you even received the realtime data.

Comment: Hi, so it works however I am having one problem. If I add a new pet in the database on the addPetPage and come back to the page with the collectionView it doesn't update the collection view unless I logout the user then Log back in. Why would that be?

Comment: @user2773611 For changes made only inside the database to appear in your collection you will have to query the database again. A simple idea would be to add a Button on your collectionView for that. This button would then be bound to a Command in your ViewModel that requeries the database and adds the pets that are not yet existant in your collection. There may be some really smart solutions for your problem, but sadly none that i'm aware of. Good luck :)